# BeautifulSoup example given in Python documents not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying out example given in BeautifulSoup documentation and one of the example is not giving intended result

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>

<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their     names were
 <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>, 
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
<p class="story">...</p>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

In the example it says

```
soup.find_all('b')
# [<b>The Dormouse's story</b>]
```

but when I try the same command I am getting error as below

```
>>> soup.find_all('b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

but soup object is not None

```
>>> soup

<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their    
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
<p class="story">...</p>
</html>
```

I am not sure why the given example is not working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when using BeautifulSoup 4. Using BeautifulSoup version *three* however, gives exactly your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using BeautifulSoup version **three**, not version four.

In BeautifulSoup 3, the method is called `findAll()`, not `find_all()`. Because using an attribute that is not recognized is translated to `soup.find('unrecognized_attribute')`, you asked BeautifulSoup to find you the first `<find_all>` *HTML element*, which doesn't exist so `None` is returned.

Use BeautifulSoup 4 instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

where you almost certainly instead used:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup  # version 3
```

You'll need to install the `beautifulsoup4` project.

Demo:

```
>>> html_doc = """
... <html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
... 
... <p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
... 
... <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their     names were
...  <a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>, 
... <a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
... <a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
... <p class="story">...</p>
... """
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> soup.find_all('b')
[<b>The Dormouse's story</b>]
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> soup.find_all('b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```